# How do I simply create a mesh line?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm currently teaching myself Blender and have been going through the online documentation. Many of the examples are using nothing but lines of vertices/edges but I can't see how I do that. For instance, how would I "create a mesh representing the profile of your object" as it says in this example?:
[image]

Comment: A suggestion is to see a tutorial series.  Here is one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw .  Of course you can search for tutorials on many websites.  If by online documentation you mean the written documentation by only one party, try to consider tutorial videos as well.

Comment: There can be many ways to model an object. You may find this method helpful for your object https://vimeo.com/channels/blendervideotutorials/44841826

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your view to top orthographic (numpad <kbd>7</kbd> for top, numpad <kbd>5</kbd> to toggle perspective/ortho).
Add a plane (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, select Mesh/plane in the menu).
Enter Edit Mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
Select the 2 vertices on the right (<kbd>R click</kbd> to select, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R Click</kbd> to add to selection) and delete them with <kbd>X</kbd> and select "vertices" in the delete menu.
Now you can move your vertices where you need.
[image]
Select one and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L Click</kbd> to create one more where you click.
[image]
continue until you have your profile done.
[image]